# getting runtime error when updating paging library from 3.0.0-alpha10 to 3.0.0-alpha12

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

i created my pagingSource class with paging 3.0.0-alpha10 and it worked but when i changed the version to  3.0.0-alpha12,
i got this error
this is the runtime exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.Object androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer.presentNewList(androidx.paging.NullPaddedList, androidx.paging.NullPaddedList, androidx.paging.CombinedLoadStates, int, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)"
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1$lambda$1.invokeSuspend(PagingDataDiffer.kt:136)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1$lambda$1.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:161)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:133)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:61)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:11)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:236)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:362)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.completeResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:479)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractChannel$ReceiveElement.completeResumeReceive(AbstractChannel.kt:899)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ArrayChannel.offerInternal(ArrayChannel.kt:84)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractSendChannel.send(AbstractChannel.kt:135)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.doInitialLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:315)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$doInitialLoad$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:11)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

and this is my PaginSource:

```
import androidx.paging.PagingSource
import com.example.template.api.MyApi
import com.example.template.api.responses.ChatHistoryResponse
import retrofit2.HttpException
import java.io.IOException

class ChatHistoryPagingSource
constructor(
    private val myApi: MyApi,
    private val search: String,
    private val type: String,
    private val token: String,
    private val status: String,
    ): PagingSource<Int, ChatHistoryResponse>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, ChatHistoryResponse> {
        val position = params.key ?: 1
        return try {
            val response = myApi.chatHistoryList(token, status, position, 20, type, search)
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = response,
                prevKey = if (position == 1) null else position -1,
                nextKey = if (response.isEmpty()) null else position +1
            )

        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            LoadResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }

}
```

it works completely in the previous version but I have to migrate to the new one.

Comment: I used version 3.0.0-alpha13 and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, the gradle dependencies you are using are not compatible with each other.

In my case, the exception occurred when I used `androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.0-alpha05` with `androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha12`. I fixed it by bumping version of paging compose to `1.0.0-alpha13`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I do not use Compose yet

Comment: Do you mind sharing your app's gradle dependencies with us? @Sergiob

Comment: kotlin_version = '1.5.20'
        kotlin_coroutines = '1.4.1'
        gradle_plugin_ver = '1.5.31'
        nav_version = "2.3.5"
        android_material = "1.4.0"
        room_version = "2.4.0-beta01"
        paging_version = "3.0.1"        
        desugar_ver = "1.1.1"
        fragment_ver = "1.3.6"
        recycler_view = "1.2.1"
        recycler_view_selection = "1.1.0"
        buildToolsVer = '30.0.2'
        desugar_jdk = '1.1.1'
        live_data_ver = '2.3.1'
        build_gradle_ver = '7.0.3'
        data_binding_ver = '3.1.4'

Comment: @Sergiob it's the same error and the same root cause.  Update your Paging version to 3.1.0-beta01 and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: As I wrote before, I tried, it doesn't work; same error

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue while using `androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.2` and `androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0-alpha12`.

I fixed it by changing the paging version to `3.1.0`.