# New Jetpack paging library makes app crash - NEW

Tags: android, kotlin, paging, android-jetpack

I've updated the following libraries:

```
 - kotlin.reflect to 1.5.31
 - room.paging to 2.4.0-alpha05
 - room.ktx to 2.4.0-alpha05
```

and now all features of my app that use list of Room objects with Flow and Paging (all my RecyclerViews actually) crash with the following vague exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.Object androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer.presentNewList(androidx.paging.NullPaddedList, androidx.paging.NullPaddedList, int, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)"
    at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(PagingDataDiffer.kt:151)
    at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
    at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:165)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
    at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:135)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:62)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl(Channels.kt:1)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:244)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:398)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.completeResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:514)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractChannel$ReceiveElement.completeResumeReceive(AbstractChannel.kt:907)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ArrayChannel.offerInternal(ArrayChannel.kt:83)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractSendChannel.send(AbstractChannel.kt:134)
    at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.doInitialLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:318)
    at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.access$doInitialLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:55)
    at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$doInitialLoad$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

If I restore the previous version of the libraries everything works fine once again. Please help !

**NOTE:**

Do not bind this question to the following one:
[Paging crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65992527/getting-runtime-error-when-updating-paging-library-from-3-0-0-alpha10-to-3-0-0-a)
because the answer to that question is not even related to this one because the Compose package is not used or even included in my project, and it doesn't work ( I tested it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Paging 3.1.0-beta01 to fix, or revert Room back to stable 2.3.0.

The Paging library seems to have broken binary compatibility between 3.0.x and 3.1.0, and Room 2.4.0-alpha05+ is using the updated contract.

This is most likely related to the new `room-paging` library.  They talk a lot about new paging interop requirements in the release notes, but I don't see anything which calls out strict version requirements. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.4.0-beta01

Comment: To make it work I must restore the previous version, that is clear. But that means I only delay the problem. I need a fix for the new package, at least if that is not a bug in the package. If it is a bug, than it is clearly fine for me

Comment: The fix is to use compatible dependencies.  As it is right now, if you want to use the Room beta with Paging you must also use the Paging beta.

Comment: Changing paging to 3.1.0-beta01 is the way to go. Thanks